# Sencha build package localstorage quota

Tags: browser, sencha-touch-2, local-storage, mobile-safari

I am trying to build my application for production and using the below command.

```
sencha app build production
```

It is working fine on a desktop browsers but when I am going to run from the iPhone Safari browser via URL, I am getting the localstorage quota access limit error. I can understand the browser limit on a device is 5MB but I am not saving a single entity in a localstorage but still getting this error.

What I investigated is When the sencha app is build for production, app.js is saved in the localstorage and the app.css is also saved in the localstorage, that consumes the whole quota limit.

What should be the expected and elegant solutions to resolve this issue? One solution is to remove app.js remove from the app.json and add it explicitly in the index.html but it looks like a KLUDGE. Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

The production mode is intended for production server and javascript and css files are cached when you open them in the browser. You can do sencha app build package which will not cache the files in the browser.

The link discusses this issue in detail http://andidog.de/blog/2012/07/dont-use-sencha-touch-production-mode-build-for-mobile/

Comment: Thanks Kathir but what the performance increases in production mode will increase it in the build package? Secondly, build package I guess doesn't minify css & javascript, does it?

Answer (score 0):

You add external scripts, css files and folders through app.json. From there you can config how these files should be threaded.

```
"css": [
    {
        "path": "resources/css/app.css",
        "remote": true
    }
],
```

Or you can add external files by using the loader object from within app.js

```
Ext.Loader.loadScriptFile()
```

Shared code other then packages or themes, like your own framework files/objects, can also be added by using the loader object

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        'Resources': 'resources/translations'
    }
});
```